# Robô para informações

Tags: php, javascript, google, app

Bom dia, Tarde , Noite.
gostaria de sabe se tem como criar um robô onde ele pega alguns preços de produto, e joga essa informação em um app.
estou com uma ideia para um app e sou iniciante ainda estou fazendo logica de programação e depois vou fazer java script

Comment: Cara.... o que você quer não é um robô, e sim um programa. Tente melhorar a qualidade da sua pergunta, pois quase não entendi ela (o que fazer javascript tem á ver com a pergunta??).

Answer (score 1):

Creio que você quiz fazer referência ao Robo no caso de "algo que torne seu aplicativo capaz de consumir dados de Preços de algum lugar", no caso consumir dados de um banco de dados de preços por exemplo, ou consumir dados de uma API ok ("Application Programming Interface").

Na verdade existem diversas formas de entender sua dúvida, como você falou em Javascript seria interessante abrir uma ideia para você consumir estes dados via "Ajax" por exemplo, onde através da sua programação em Jscript você irá direcionar uma requisição de "GET" para seu aplicativo Web consumir seus dados de Preços, por exemplo por uma API retornando estes dados em formato JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). Então estes dados estariam dispostos em uma URL por exemplo: http://xxxx_precos_de_produtos , onde estariam num formato tipo assim: `{ "_idproduto" : "001", "nome_produto":"chuteira", "preco_produto":"150,00"}`.

Como falei acima existem outras formas de consumir dados, através de consultas diretamente ao banco de dados via querys e SQL (Structured Query Language), por exemplo, utilizando linguagens como PHP, Java, Python, etc.

Veja que há muitos caminhos e formas de se consumir dados! Tentei elucidar sua dúvida de uma forma simples, já que está iniciando e todo inicio é realmente confuso, mas continue em frente, estude, busque informação e tenha sucesso! Abraço.

Comment: Muito obrigado ^^, estou fazendo em python, utiizando o selenium conseguir pegar alguns dados. Mas ainda estou estudando MySQL, pois estou salvando esses preços em XLS e JASON